# Cisco. Не удаётся подключиться с Linux через SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, cisco

Не удаётся подключиться к маршрутизатору *Cisco* из *Linux* через *SSH-клиент*. При выполнении подключения с логированием видим следующее:

```
ssh -v 10.0.0.1
. . .
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
Connection closed by 10.0.0.1
```

При этом через *Putty* подключение проходит.

С чем связана эта проблема и как её обойти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема связана с тем, что *Cisco* и *SSH-клиент* не могут в автоматическом режиме договориться об алгоритме обмена ключами (Key  Exchange, KEX). Чтобы подключение прошло, нужно указать *SSH-клиенту* явно, что надо использовать алгоритм `diffie-hellman-group14-sha1`, указав его в опциях подключения (ключ `-o`):

```
ssh -o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 10.0.0.1
```